# Conditionals in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a method that is intended to generate an addition problem, get the user's answer from the command line, then output if they are right or wrong:

```
def questionPromt
    firstNumber = rand(20)
    secondNumber = rand(20)
    equation = firstNumber + secondNumber
    puts "What is #{firstNumber} + #{secondNumber} ?"
    useranswer = gets.chomp
    if equation == useranswer
        puts "good job "
    else
        puts "wrong answer"
    end
end
```

However, it always defaults to the incorrect condition, and I can't get it to work. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing string `useranswer` from prompt and the `equation` number

Try to use `to_i` for `useranswer`

```
useranswer = gets.to_i
```

Comment: Didn't realize gets.chomp stored input as a string, thanks

Comment: got it @CarySwoveland. I've edited my answer. Thanks